# How to interpret glow/corona/arc discharge IV diagram?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

There's a current/voltage graph on wikipedia for glow discharge that I don't understand.

Aren't we driving the voltage? How can the line possibly go *down* on the voltage axis i.e. have two values of current for a particular driving voltage? Is this some kind of hysteresis effect? What does the graph look like if you slowly increase the voltage from zero?

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glow_discharge#/media/File:Glow_discharge_current-voltage_curve_English.svg]

Comment: tentative answer: the resistance drops as the gas gets ionized... it is hysteresis and in theory you could use it to construct a rectifier/diode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in diagrams like these, the power supply driving the discharge is *current-limited* so when you get into the "line going down" zones, the current does not rise without bound and degenerate into a power arc.

The voltage required to achieve a given current flow in the glow discharge regime goes down because as more and more of the electrode area gets covered with discharge, the gap resistance goes down- until the entire electrode area is glowing. This means it takes less voltage to *sustain* a glow discharge than it takes to *initiate* it.